# Python Selenium Right Click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, contextmenu

Trying to find some text and then right click on that text. The table is dynamic so I cannot presume to know the cell positions of where the value to search for is or the value to click on. so for example I want to find a name and then right click on the name itself

The right click menu seems to be called **class = context menu**, and the values are **class = context_item** (See attached screenshots) (html included also)

I know that this part works, but the rest below it is having an issue - col = `row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text() , "Luke Wilson")]')`

### OUTPUT

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\ffox_Change_Create_Save_Stay_v2.py",
>   line 182, in 
>       get_all_rows_approval()   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\ffox_Change_Create_Save_Stay_v2.py",
>   line 164, in get_all_rows_approval
>       menu = col.find_element_by_class_name("context_menu")   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 398, in find_element_by_class_name
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 654, in find_element
>       {"using": by, "value": value})['value']   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 628, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: .context_menu

#

Code snippet

```
def get_all_rows_approval():

    approval_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_table"]/tbody')
    rows = approval_table.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval')]")
    for row in rows:
        col = row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text() , "Luke Wilson")]')
        menu = col.find_element_by_class_name("context_menu")
        actions = ActionChains(menu)
        actions.move_to_element(menu)
        actions.click(menu)
        actions.perform()
```

#### html for the table

```
                     <tbody class="list2_body">
                        <tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" class="list_row list_odd" style="" sys_id="30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=task_ci&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <span class="sr-only"></span>
                              <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
                              <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=30f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="97000fcc0a0a0a6e0104ca999f619e5b" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=97000fcc0a0a0a6e0104ca999f619e5b">Christen Mitchell</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
                              <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
                              <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" class="list_row list_even" style="" sys_id="34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=2&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <span class="sr-only"></span>
                              <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
                              <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=34f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=2&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="46d96f57a9fe198101947a9620895886" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=46d96f57a9fe198101947a9620895886">Luke Wilson</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
                              <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
                              <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" class="list_row list_odd" style="" sys_id="b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=3&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <span class="sr-only"></span>
                              <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
                              <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b4f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961998&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=3&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="ee826bf03710200044e0bfc8bcbe5de6" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=ee826bf03710200044e0bfc8bcbe5de6">Bernard Laboy</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
                              <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
                              <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="row_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" class="list_row list_even" style="" sys_id="b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" record_class="sysapproval_approver" data-updated-on="2018-07-30 13:36:23" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval">
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1"><span class="input-group-checkbox"><input title="Mark record for List Action" id="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" name="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" data-original-title="Mark record for List Action" type="checkbox"><label for="check_change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997" style="" class="checkbox-label"><span class="sr-only">Select record for action</span></label></span></td>
                           <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1"><a href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_view=&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=4&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval" style="margin-left:0px"><span class="sr-only">Preview</span></a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <span class="sr-only"></span>
                              <div class="list2_cell_background" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
                              <a class="linked formlink" href="sysapproval_approver.do?sys_id=b8f168b2dbeb5300b58ad360cf961997&amp;sysparm_record_target=sysapproval_approver&amp;sysparm_record_row=4&amp;sysparm_record_rows=5&amp;sysparm_record_list=sysapproval%3De6d1ac72dbeb5300b58ad360cf96193e%5EORDERBYorder">Requested</a>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="62d78687c0a8010e00b3d84178adc913" href="sys_user.do?sys_id=62d78687c0a8010e00b3d84178adc913">Ron Kettering</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""><a class="linked" sys_id="b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a" href="sys_user_group.do?sys_id=b85d44954a3623120004689b2d5dd60a">CAB Approval</a></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable=""></td>
                           <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
                              <div class="datex date-calendar" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">2018-07-30 06:36:23</div>
                              <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="just now" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="5m ago">07-30 06:36</div>
                              <div class="datex date-timeago" title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" timeago="2018-07-30 13:36:23" data-original-title="2018-07-30 06:36:23" null="5m ago">5m ago</div>
                           </td>
                           <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
                        </tr>

                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <a id="change_request.sysapproval_approver.sysapproval_bottom" href="javascript:function(evt){if(evt){evt.stopPropagation();}}"><span class="sr-only">Bottom of table</span></a>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `click()` will not do **right click**, it is `context_click()`

If you want to right click on based on name, then you can use this code :

```
ActionChains(driver).context_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Luke Wilson']").perform()
```

You can try with this also :

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Luke Wilson']")).perform();
action.context_click().perform()
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks  
---
       actions = ActionChains(driver)      
    menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Luke Wilson"]')  
    actions.context_click(menu)  
    actions.perform()

Comment: You need to add the import of ActionChains to be a complete solution.

Comment: The import for ActionChains is from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains