# In Selenium with python ,how to move mouse pointer (using pyautogui) to click on an element whose xpath is known?

Tags: python, selenium, coordinates, pyautogui

I want to do a right click on a link and move down the context menu . I have retrieved the location of the xpath(of the link) using the xpath.location and it gives.. let us say {'x': 28, 'y': 386} as coordinates. I want the mouse pointer to move to this coordinate and do a right click . For this I am using pyautogui.moveTo(28,386) .But the pointer is doing a right click at a different location and not on the link specified by the xpath. How can I click exactly on the link? Why are the coordinates specified by xpath.location different from those identified by the pyautogui?

Answer (score 0):

*As your problem seem to be X-Y issue I suggest you below solutions*

You can do the same much easier:

**1.**

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('<XPATH>')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('target','_blank')", link)
link.click()
```

This will change `target` attribute of link node to `'_blank'` which imply to *open link in new tab*

P.S. Note that this code will **physically make changes in DOM**

**2.**

```
window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
URL = link.get_attribute('href')
driver.execute_script('window.open(URL, "_blank";')
```

This allows to open URL in new tab

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to navigate through the context menu and select different options as needed. So how do i do that ? I think I should rewrite the question .Sorry for the confusion . The main focus is on getting contextclick and navigating through the menu

Comment: @Lucky1234 , oh... I see... Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619434/python-selenium-right-click/51619869#51619869) ?

Comment: i tried using Actionchains.contextclick  but it is not working. I am not able to view the context menu .Also i tried sending keys arrowdown and return but it is also not working .Thats when i came across pyautogui and thought to give it a try . It actually displays the context menu but not able to direct the location of the pointer to where i want it .

Comment: I tried the answers from the below link too. Not working
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428026/select-an-option-from-the-right-click-menu-in-selenium-webdriver-java.   @DonnyFlaw